# Is thread switching only occuring when time.sleep(1) or IO requests?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

From reading and on-hand excersising I came to this conclusion:

Inside a function the thread execution will not stop until it hits an time.sleep(1), a I/O request. Otherwise a thread will just follow through the instructions inside a function then move to the next.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I am no Python guy but this is very unlikely. More likely threads are time-sliced and can be switched any time.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, yes I read that part in the oficcial documentation, says for python 3.2+ it force switching every 500 ms. I still don't understand, or at least not sure if there is any other cases where python just arbitarily switch thread, other than those cases I listed.